# sort is very slow for big files

Tags: performance, text-processing, sort, file-sorting

I want to sort file (with removing duplicates) which contains wordlist with a size of almost 25GB. I am using `sort` command in Ubuntu terminal but it takes hours to output sorted file, the command is:

```
sort -u input.txt>output.txt
```

Is there some alternative and efficient way to do the same?

Comment: Can the file even fit into your RAM? If not, does it reside on an SSD? What are your HW specs actually? I am not sure if the `sort` command works multithreaded, that’s the only chance to improve the performance on the same machine IMHO.

Comment: I also use sort --parallel=16 -uo list-sorted.txt inputfile.txt. It also take much time

Comment: If you only need to filter duplicates, you could try if `awk` would be faster... `awk '!s[$0]{print;s[$0]=1;}' input.txt > output.txt`.

Comment: @Melebius sort uses parallel by default and it is equal to the amount of cpu's with a max of 8 (above 8 it tends to be slower on most systems).

Comment: Limitation here is memory indeed: that large file does not fit in RAM so SWAP and perhaps temporary files are being used. Powerful as the GNU tools are though, it still works, though. Importing in a database and doing the sort there might be faster, but still expect long processing times.

Comment: have you tried splitting the file and merging them with the `-m` option?  (it is called "merge sort"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

Comment: @Rinzwind in my experiences it doesn't make much of differences, also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/279099/64321

Comment: please could you add some example rows?

Answer (score 4):

From my personal experience: if you want unique lines make sure you also use

```
LC_ALL=C sort -u
```

I see speed improvements by a factor 10 but it probably depends on the characters in the file (I often have to use it for translations so I have accented characters in the file).

Answer (score 0):

A really incredible tool is xsv (https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv). Running it for a 3173959 rows file

```
xsv sort input.txt >output.csv
```

I have the output in 3 seconds

Comment: What sorting algorithm does it use? The [complexity of sorting](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-complexities-of-all-sorting-algorithms/) is more than linear for most of them. Moreover, we don’t know your and OP’s HW specs and both of you are using a different data set… This is like comparing apples with oranges.

Comment: @Melebius thank you. For the algorithm you could ask in repo; you could find useful this benchmark https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv/blob/master/BENCHMARKS.md. I have no idea of the source file, the one I have used is this http://burntsushi.net/stuff/worldcitiespop.csv